# PS/2 mouse light goes out randomly

Tags: windows, mouse, ps2

I have a problem where the light on my optical PS/2 mouse goes out for a few seconds. When it goes out, the cursor stops moving, but clicks still work.

I have already tried another mouse and it experiences this same problem. I have also reinstalled Windows, restored the mouse drivers and changed the mouse buffer size to no effect.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe a faulty PS/2 port. Have you tried the other PS/2 port?  Usually there's two, and often they'll work for either the keyboard or mouse (you may have to hard-reset or power cycle to get it to recognize the port change).   Did it ever work right?

Answer (score 2):

If this problem is reproducible using another OS (e.g. a Linux live system like Knoppix), I would suspect a loose contact on the PS/2 jack/PCB. This would probably be easy to fix if you are used to solder, but a rather high risk to damage the mainboard further if you are not.

Would using a USB mouse be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a faulty PS/2 port, can you try the device in another PC, maybe time for a USB related upgrade :)